# jQuery the new appended data can not be captured by .on()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get the value of an input box that been `.append()` to the HTML recently. The Input box does not exist normally. it get `.append()` on button click by a function.

The Value of the input should be captured and sent via jQuery Ajax to backend(php).

**The Function which append the Input field:**

```
function toggleOrder(){
    $(".orderContainer").append(`
        <div class="orderFilterBox">
            <input id="orderFilterInput" type="text" placeHolder="Enter IMEI">
        </div>
    `);
}
```

**The Function where the input value captured and sent to backend**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#orderFilterInput").on("change paste",function(){
        //DO THE MAGIC
        //...
    });
});
```

I belive that the problem being there that the code on the pageload where the input not exist. im not sure how to avoid that.

Also if you would suggsest a better question title to help other people, then please go for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `.on` you need focus on static element which exist in page load. orderFilterInput.on is bad if orderFilterInput does not exist.

You can try

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){
    $("body").on("change paste","#orderFilterInput", function(){
        //DO THE MAGIC
        //...
    });
});
```

or you can make your append button by jquery with event in your append function.

```
const btn = $('<input id="orderFilterInput" type="text" placeHolder="Enter IMEI">')
  .on('copy paste', function() { .. });

$container.append(btn);
```

Comment: Okey, that looks like what im looking for. i appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
> must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure
> the elements are present and can be selected, place scripts after the
> elements in the HTML markup or perform event binding inside a document
> ready handler. Alternatively, use delegated event handlers to attach
> event handlers.
>
> Delegated event handlers have the advantage that they can process
> events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a
> later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at
> the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use
> delegated event handlers to avoid the need to frequently attach and
> remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of
> a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if
> the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the
> document. The document element is available in the head of the
> document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events
> there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Here is the api reference:
https://api.jquery.com/on/
, So as suggested by **@daremachine** you need to use the delegated event handler
as:

```
$(document).on("change paste","#orderFilterInput", function(){
    //DO THE MAGIC
    //...
});
```

Comment: Alright, Thank you for explaining. i'll see what i can do